# Midnight commander язык по умолчанию

Tags: ubuntu

Как сделать так, чтобы *Midnight commander* запускался из консоли по команде `mc` на английском языке?

Сейчас он запускается на русском, а чтобы запустить на английском надо вводить

```
$ LANG=en_EN.UTF-8 mc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В самом mc так сделать нельзя. В Linux приложение смотрит на пользовательскую локаль, и в зависимости от нее подтягивает нужный язык.
Я бы предложил Вам прописать алиас на команду запуска mc. Это не очень эстетичное решение, но оно будет работать:

```
alias mc='LANG=en_EN.UTF-8 mc'
```

Для применения изменений потребуется сделать `source ~./bashrc` или logout

Comment: а как селать так, чтобы язык сохранялся и после перезагрузки системы?

Comment: Можно добавить строку выше в файл ~/.bashrc. И выполнить соответственно source ~./bashrc или logout

Comment: всё получилось, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

У меня CentOS но может в Ubunti будет тоже самое. Есть файл `/etc/mc/cedit.menu` там есть настройки.

```
unset LANG
unset LANGUAGE
LC_ALL=
```

Попробуйте тут настроить, может поможет.